# golang: web service that monitors worker goroutine

Tags: rest, go

Suppose I'm writing a REST web service in golang. Internally I have several worker goroutine that does things. Such goroutine are triggered on demand by the HTTP API. Of course I'd like to monitor the progress of these goroutines somehow. Normally there will be a channel for the goroutine to send updates, error, etc. And the main program would do `select` on those channels.

However, because the even loop of the main program is busy with `http.ListenAndServe()`, I can't see a way to achieve this. Given that this seems like a quite common issue to have, I'm wondering if there is a design pattern that I'm missing.

[EDIT]
Some more technical detail. So I have a `Resource` class that manages a pool of resources. `Resource.DoSomething()` is a long operation, so it'll kick of a goroutine in the back ground. A channel will be opened to allow status to be polled.

When a certain HTTP request comes in, this `DoSomething()` gets triggered. But I have no context to poll the status from. Currently my silly plan is to poll the channel for input when the *next* HTTP request comes in. This should be sufficient but not ideal - I'd like to know what's going on in that goroutine right away.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? I'm not sure what you are confused about.

Answer (score 3):

Launch a Go routine to specifically run the select that contains the monitoring, putting the select in it's own `for` loop:

```
func main() {

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            //TODO: Insert Code Here?
            }
        }
    }()

    err := http.ListenAndServe()

    if err != nil {
        //TODO:
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm. This is for monitoring the goroutines, right? How does it linked into the HTTP monitoring loop?

Comment: If you're not looking to roll your own then how about a framework? https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni contains a logging middleware maybe that would do?

Comment: using go routine before `ListenAndServe()` is OK. But I'd like to handle everything in the same thread.

Comment: @lang2 goroutines are multiplexed over threads, and at the moment by default everything runs on a single thread.